# What is the address of a pointer in C?

Tags: c, pointers, memory-address, ansi-c

```
    int main()
    {
    int *p;

    printf("%p \n", &p);
    printf("%p \n", p);

    return 0;
    }
```

By executing this code I am receiving the following output:

```
    0x16b77f710 
    0x104683f4c
```

I expected to get the same memory address, because the `&p` id not referenced to any other variable.

Why i am getting two different memory address?

Thanks,

Comment: Because p doesn't point to itself.

Comment: `int *p;` does not initialize `p`, so `printf("%p \n", p);` prints some random garbage value

Comment: You would need `void *p = &p;` to get the same output.

Comment: The program tries to use a variable that was not initialised. This has undefined behaviour. The output can be anything at all. "because the &p id not referenced to any other variable" is a non-sequitur.

Answer (score 2):

The pointer is a normal object having (in your case type of `int *`). It cant point to itself because the type of such pointer would have to be `int **`

[image]

*image stolen from internet.

Answer (score 2):

A pointer is a variable like any other.  It has an address, which is typically the address in memory where that variable sits.

Like any other variable, a pointer variable also has some data in it.  For a pointer variable, that data is the address of *some other variable*, the variable at which the pointer points.

The address of a variable, and the contents of a variable, are two totally different things.  They are almost never equal.

Try this program, in which I give your variable `p` something to point to:

```
int main()
{
    int i = 5;
    int *p = &i;

    printf("p: %p, p's address: %p\n", p, &p);
    printf("i: %d, i's address: %p\n", i, &i);
}
```

You should notice two things:

1. As in your first program, "p" and "p's address" will be different.
2. Whatever value you see for "p", it will be the same as "i's address".

Comment: IMO the best answer. A minor nitpick: `%p` requires a void-pointer so there should be a cast of `&p` and `&i`

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that a pointer, when declared, does not point to itself by default. Simplified you can imagine it in such a way that a pointer occupies 2 memory cells. 1 memory cell has the virtual address where the pointer itself is located (&p in your case), the 2nd memory cell contains the virtual address where the pointer points to (p in your case).

Since memory cells retain their value when they are deallocated, the cell containing the destination address of your pointer still contains an obsolete value from another, already completed process.

You would have the same phenomenon if you declare a new integer variable and then print its value with printf, you will see that there will already be some number in the new variable that will appear completely random. This is also due to the fact that there is still an obsolete value in the corresponding memory cell.

Comment: Just be precise in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Let assume there is random memory block for just understanding name it `a`. Now assume that `p` is pointing to that memory block.

`&p` returns the address of memory block where `p` is present.

`p` returns the address of memory block(`&a`) to the variable/memory block(`a`) which `p` is pointing.

So of course it will give different memory addresses.

Answer (score 0):

> I expected to get the same memory address, because the &p id not referenced to any other variable.

Pointer variables do not automatically point to themselves; if you don't explicitly initialize them, then their initial value will be *indeterminate* (or `NULL`, depending on how they are declared).

There's nothing magic about pointer variables - like any other scalar, they store some kind of value; it's just that in their case, that value is an address of another object.

If you *really* want `p` to store its own address, you'll have to do something like

```
p = (int *) &p;
```

The cast is necessary because the type of the *expression* `&p` is `int **`, and you can't assign a pointer value of one type to a variable of a different pointer type.  But, pointers to different types are not guaranteed to have the same size, representation, or alignment.  On modern commodity hardware like x86 you can probably count on `int *` and `int **` having the same size and representation, just be aware that doesn't *have* to be the case everywhere.